# Android: How to use a Android Pad as a customer information Terminal

Tags: android

I want to us an Android-powered Pad as an information terminal for my customers.

The only thing it has to to is to show a HTML5 Webpage.

Therefore, 
1. it should not be posiible to show another website (only the local one), should be no problem

1. it should be only possible to leave the app with a password (how?)
2. and all buttons should be disabled (that´s hard).

I found out how to set the target for the home button, but maybe there is an existing solution.

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I assume you understand the easiest way to do this is to develop an Android native application to show your webpage. This is done by using a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html), but the support of HTML5 depends on the platform, so if you use any video or audio, you may need some hooks.

Trhough a WebView, you can filter which urls can be opened or not.

And well, I don't think there are many problems on exiting only when a password is entered.

Regarding to number 2, AFAIK, you can let your Activity ("window" of the application) to handle most of keys, but obviously you can't map the power key.

But I have to confess, when you develop an application, you always find some issues... so probably is not that easy as I wrote in these lines... Good luck!